# Is it necessary to put linear layouts in android development?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

So recently I have been learning android development and my question is that **"what is the diffrence between using layouts(mostly linear) & not using them in an activity?"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**LinearLayout** is a view group that aligns all children in a single direction, vertically or horizontally.

it totally depends on your design and your requirements which layout you use

You can use only **Relative** and **Linear** layout both together as well.